# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL

Tags: php, api, error, soap, wsdl

I'm running magento in local on Xampp.
I'm trying to create a soap service but I have this error.
When i try this URL : `http://localhost:8080/magento/api/v2_soap/?wsdl`
I see the xml document but when i try `http://localhost:8080/magento/api/v2_soap/index` I have the PHP error that you can see below. 
After that all my magento projects are redirected to wizard installation. But when I close and reopen my xampp all project are come back and are accessible!

Where is the problem? There is something else to configure for running a soap API?

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>WSDL</faultcode>
<faultstring>SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 
     'http://localhost:8080/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1' : 
 failed to load external entity 
     "http://localhost:8080/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1"
</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

In my log file I had

```
[26-Jun-2014 09:28:52 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: 
Couldn't load from 'http://localhost:8080/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1' 
: failed to load external entity 
"http://localhost:8080/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1"
 in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Zend\Soap\Server.php on line 811
```

In this line of code I have. I don't know if it can be useful

```
  protected function _getSoap()
{
    $options = $this->getOptions();
    $server  = new SoapServer($this->_wsdl, $options); **<- I had this 

    if (!empty($this->_functions)) {
        $server->addFunction($this->_functions);
    }
```

Comment: check your log file.

Comment: I edit my question with my log file

Comment: "After that all my magento projects are redirected to wizard installation." > Sounds like the latest Magento bug a patch was released for. Are you using Magento 1.9? If so, install the patch and try again: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/33529/231