# Bug in CE version 1.9.0.1 connecting via Soap v1?

Tags: soap, ce-1.9.0.1

I spent the last two days debugging a problem that caused my site to randomly redirect to the index.php/install page. I solved the problem by clearing the cache and the sessions folder, and then rebooting the server. I found the event that triggered the bug. The problem occurs when I try to add a service reference in MS visual studio 2012 using the following links.

```
http://magentohost/api/?wsdl 
http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl
```

Using these two URLS cause the following error in the error log.

```
    [Thu Jul 24 08:20:40 2014] [error] [client 10.0.0.115] PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://hostname.com/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1&wsdl%2F_vti_bin%2FListData_svc%2F%24metadata=' : failed to load external entity "http://hostname.com/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1&wsdl%2F_vti_bin%2FListData_svc%2F%24metadata="\n in /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Soap/Server.php on line 811

[Thu Jul 24 08:20:46 2014] [error] [client 10.0.0.115] PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't find <definitions> in 'http://hostname.com/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1&wsdl%2Fmex=' in /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Soap/Server.php on line 811
```

Here is line 811 of Server.php

**$server  = new SoapServer($this->_wsdl, $options);**

I tried connecting to those URLS on CE version 1.8.0 alpha and they worked fine.

I just recently upgraded from version 1.8.0 alpha to 1.9.0.1.

The following URL doesn't cause a problem in CE version 1.9.0

```
http://magentohost/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1
```

Does anyone know if this is a bug in CE version 1.9.0.1 or is it an error in my upgrade? 
Can you not connect to soap v1 with visual studio 2012?

Comment: I am trying to solve the same issue Try using this on line 767 in Mage.php before simplexml_load_file libxml_disable_entity_loader(false); I am searching for rest of the solution and the reason for this issue

Answer (score 7):

This is an already known and patched Magento Bug.

> Magento Install Page Displays After SOAP v2 Index Page Refresh
>
> Patch name: SUPEE-3762. Refreshing the SOAP v2 index page
>   (`http://your-magento-host-name/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/`) results
>   in all administrators and customers viewing the Magento installation
>   page.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce19-later-release-notes#ce19-patches-soap

You can get the patch file (SUPEE-3762) from the download page:
SUPEE-3762 - Prevents repeated SOAP index page call issue from causing customers to only see the Magento installation page - Added Aug 12, 2014
http://www.magentocommerce.com/download

Comment: Sorry, I read over the fact that you're using SOAPv1. I didn't test if this patch solves your issue then.